# Запоминание состояния страницы

Tags: php, ajax, сессия

День добрый.
Имеется доска объявлений. При загрузке страницы показывается определённый лимит объявлений. Имеется кнопка "Далее" при клике на которую идёт обращение через ajax к php файлу который выгребает следующую порцию объявлений. Передаются значения с какой позиции выбирайть записи для LIMIT .

Так как подгрузка данных динамическая то при переходе на другую страницу и последующем возврате на страницу с объявлениями выводится первоначальное количество.

Задача стоит при возвращении выводить то количество объявлений которое было подгружено.

Пытался реализовать заведением в сессии переменной сколько было подгружено объявлений. Но есть проблемы:
1) Время жизни сессии - накликав один раз, при последующих заходах(через час, сутки итд) будет выводить портянку, что не есть хорошо. Как вариант можно добавить метку времени и сравнивать с текущим - если старше 1 минуты обнулять переменную.
2) Для каждой категории потребуется заводить свою переменную в сессии. При большой посещяемости количество переменных в сессии будет расти очень сильно.

Сталкивался ли кто то с подобным или может кто то свежим взглядом может подсказать более оптимальное решение?

Comment: а почему сессия, а не куки? куки хоть сколько могут жить. localStorage не знаю сколько хранит, но думаю и он тоже подходит

Comment: А классическую постраничную навигацию не хотите реализовать без кнопки далее? В этом случае пользователь сам бы мог управлять состоянием - листать сначала или с определенной страницы. С сессией есть еще одна засада, что делать, если пользователь открыл две или более вкладок?

Answer (score 1):

@BOPOH дал в целом вразумительный комментарий: используйте куки и/или localStorage. Последний работает по тому же принципу, что и куки (время хранения и тд).

Есть еще один очень хороший вариант - `Zend_Session`. Если не получится использовать, как подключаемую библиотеку, то хотя бы возьмите алгоритм и реализуйте свой инструмент. Идея там в том, что сесси можно назначить время жизни и/или кол-во обращений к ней (так называемые прыжки - hops). Допустим, Вы хотите, чтобы переменная сессии жила до первого к ней обращения. Назначаете hops=1 и ни о чем больше не думаете.

Почитать о возможностях этого инструмента можно тут: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.session.advanced_usage.html (подраздел "Время жизни пространства имен").